# How to import an ASCII text file into R - the NIBRS

Tags: r

Currently, I am trying to import the National Incidence Based Reporting System (NIBRS) 2019 data into R. The data comes in an ASCII text format, and so far I've tried readr::read_tsv and readr::read_fwf. However, I can't seem to import the data correctly - read_tsv shows only 1 column, while read_fwf needs column arguments that I do not understand how to decipher based on the text file.

[Here](https://crime-data-explorer.fr.cloud.gov/downloads-and-docs) is the link to the NIBRS. I used the Master File Downloads to download the zipped file for the NIBRS in 2019.

My overall goal is to have a typical dataframe/tibble for this data set with column names being the type of crime, and the rows being the number of incidents.

I have seen a few other examples of importing this data [through this help page](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/web/pages/NACJD/guides/leaic/example-r.html), but their copies of the data only covers up to 2015 (My data needs to range from 2015-2019).

[image: Here is a screenshot of a preview of the .txt file].

Answer (score 0):

Use `read.fwf()`. Column widths are listed [here](http://s3-us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/cg-d4b776d0-d898-4153-90c8-8336f86bdfec/NIBRS_DataDictionary.pdf)

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. I tried `read.fwf(pathname, widths = c(10,10), col.names = c("AGENCY_ID","INCIDENT_ID")` to attempt to get the columns AGENCY_ID and INCIDENT_ID from the NIRBS_INCIDENT table in the data dictionary you linked to. R is still running after a few minutes, which I assume means I did something incorrectly. I assume I have to specify the table, but I don't see this in the documentation for read.fwf. I see it refers to read.table, but this doesn't look to be what I am after. Do you have an example I can follow using a couple of columns?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `read_fwf` with `column_positions`

```
library(readr)
read_fwf(filename, column_positions = c(2, 5, 10))
```

Comment: I tried using the following code: `nibrs <- read_fwf(file , fwf_positions(c(4,2,100), c("ACTIVITY_TYPE_ID","ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE","ACTIVITY_TYPE_NAME")))` for the first 3 columns in the data dictionary that @bcarlsen link. This returned an error message. Do you have a small example code chunk to get a couple specified columns?